# EmberJS - Adding a binding after creation of object

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I am trying to bind a property of an object to a property that's bound in an ArrayController. I want all of this to occur after the object has already been created and added to the ArrayController.

[Here is a fiddle with a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve](http://jsfiddle.net/EjDFS/7/).

I am wondering if I'm having problems with scope - I've already tried to bind to the global path (i.e. 'App.objectTwoController.objectOne.param3') to set the binding to. I've also tried to bind directly to the objectOneController (which is not what I want to do, but tried it just to see if it worked) and that still didn't work.

Any ideas on what I'm doing incorrectly? Thanks in advance for taking the time to look at this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the example below (I simplified it a little bit, but same principles apply)... The method below ends up looking for "objectOne" on "objectTwo" instead of on the "objectTwoController".

```
var objectTwoController: Em.Object.create({
    objectOneBinding: 'App.objectOne',
    objectTwoBinding: 'App.objectTwo',

    _onSomething: function() {
        var objectTwo = this.get('objectTwo'); 
        objectTwo.bind('param2', Em.Binding.from('objectOne.param3'));
    }.observes('something')
});
```

The problem is that you can't bind between two none relative objects.  If you look in the "connect" method in ember you will see that it only takes one reference object (this) in which to observe both paths (this is true for 9.8.1 from your example and the ember-pre-1.0 release).

You have few options (that I can think of at least).

**First**:  You can tell the objects about each other and in turn the relative paths will start working.  This will actually give "objectTwo" an object to reference when binding paths.

```
    ....
        objectTwo.set('objectOne', this.get('objectOne');
    ....
```

**Second**: You could add your own [observer/computed property](http://emberjs.com/documentation/#toc_computed-properties-setters) that will just keep the two in sync (but it is a little more verbose).  You might be able to pull off something really slick but it maybe difficult.  Even go so far as writing your own binding (like Transforms) to allow you to bind two non-related objects as long as you have paths to both.

```
    _param3: function(){
        this.setPath('objectTwo.param2', this.getPath('objectOne.param3');
    }.observes('objectOne.param3')
```

You can make these dynamically and not need to pre-define them...

**Third**:  Simply make them global paths; "App.objectOneController.content.param3" should work as your binding "_from" path (but not sure how much this helps you in your real application, because with larger applications I personally don't like everything global).

**EDIT**: When setting the full paths.  Make sure you wait until end of the current cycle before fetching the value because bindings don't always update until everything is flushed.  Meaning, your alert message needs to be wrapped in Ember.run.next or you will not see the change.

Comment: Great - thanks so much for the thorough response! I chose to go with the first route you had, as I am adding bindings between adjacent objects in my ArrayController. I was worried about Ember creating a new instance of the object when I used .set, but it seems it just refers to the same object in the memory. Seems to work great!